# alternative (ie., better choice) for Hashmap on character

Tags: java, dictionary, character, enum-map

Just as `EnumMap` is the better choice of map when working with `enum`, is there a better choice of map (rather than the generic `HashMap` that everybody uses) for dealing with character?

Characters are kind of similar to enum-members in that there are a definite number of them, so I thought there might be a 'special' kind of map for them?

[Edit]
By 'better' I meant 'faster' and uses 'less memory'

Comment: There's no better choice that I know of, but what's the down-side of just using a HashMap?

Comment: Maybe an example of what you are doing will help to understand what you mean with "better way".

Comment: By better, I meant faster (and uses less memory)

Comment: If you're limiting yourself to e.g. ASCII characters then you can use an array (you can do the same if you're using Unicode characters except the array will be pretty large).  Since characters are comparable, you can store them in a TreeMap which is more space-efficient than a HashMap since there's no load factor, except at the cost of lg(n) lookups/insertions/deletions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your question. If there are a finite number of chars, you should be able to economise on the size of the Hash map.

But you are overlooking the internationalisation thing maybe? There aren't really that 'finite' a number of chars. (real unicode has variable-length encoding etc) So I doubt there would be a good way of economising.

If you are in a particular language with e.g. 26 characters, you could consider making your own enum (or simpler, an array) for the job. If you are after a i18n-independent answer, I can't help...

Comment: Oh, I know it's a finite number of chars because this is to deal with fixed set of words in an 'artificial' language that we came up with. So the alphabet is known and fixed